# How can a DAO manage a domain, Twitter account, Github commit rights in a trustless manner?

Tags: dao, trust

With managing on-chain assets the Vault / Tresury controlled by DAO works.

With other digital assets, such as WWW domain, there is still a single human who uses GoDaddy.

Is there any technical feasibility for DAO to control the domain, ensuring that not a single human (rogue admin) can destroy the existing brand?

---

I was thinking about putting some bond system.

Whoever controls an important function that is not compatible with DAO, posts a 1000 DAI to keep them accountable.

*(don't trust, verify)*

Answer (score 1):

a purely onchain DAO cannot own anything that isn't also own chain. In a multi interoperable chain world, a DAOs reach can be extended to other chains but still excluded from owning off-chain assets. in fact, a DAO doesn't know anything that doesn't happen on-chain. it needs oracles just to get read-only information about the outside world

there are two ways to get around this problem. the first is to use a legal wrapper, the LAO are pioneers in this effort. using a legal wrapper, a DAO can do anything a traditional entity can do plus all the onchain stuff a traditional entity cant. this is very cool and works great for a bunch of near term use cases. However, you are also burdened with the constraints of the legacy legal system and erodes most of the interesting properties DAOs bring

The second way which you eluded to is to use a decentralised arbitration service. Aragon has a protocol designed specifically for this use case.
quick TL;DR, Aragon is by far the best framework to deploy a DAO with today (disclosure, I work at Aragon :) before building the first MVP the founders realised there are a bunch of agreements that will never be computable in smart contracts. To solve this they planned to build a decentralised jurisprudence system that could take into account all the subtlety of human agreements and in a way that is crypto economically secure. you can find more information on Aragon, the court system and all the other amazing stuff we are doing in the links below.

If you're interested in DAOs, have an idea for a DAO or want to DAOify your existing organisation, you can find me in our discord server

*Aragon Site*
https://aragon.org/

*Aragon Court*
https://court.aragon.org/dashboard

*Aragon Discord*
https://discord.gg/JNQvRHH

*The LAO*
https://medium.com/openlawofficial/the-lao-a-for-profit-limited-liability-autonomous-organization-9eae89c9669c

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking about hiring a law firm that has a lot of reputation at stake.

I was thinking about them putting `1m DAI` on-chain bond to Kleros Escrow.

1. If they fulfill the obligations: all good
2. If they decide to scam me: jurors are likely to decide and transfer funds to me

The transferred funds should be enough to cover the cost of legal action in the Twitter jurisdiction.

---

Follow up to that - the law firm can use "fractional ownership" of reputation bond. They could have multiple clients like me. They do not need `1m DAI` per client. It's their overall reputation capacity that makes me feel safe.

---

Ideally, we will see a raise of real-life services integrating with chain via oracles and offering 1st class citizen treatment of the DAOs.